# How are all the possible resulting values of a "StrangeLoop" explainable?

Tags: java, parallel-processing

Given a "StrangeLoop"-code like this:

2 Threads run through a loop (each) and they get and set the value of an object of the class MyInteger:

**Which results/outputs are possible?**

```
class MyInteger
{
    private int value;

    public synchronized int getValue()
    {
        return value;
    }

    public synchronized void setValue(int value)
    {
        this.value = value;
    }
}

public class StrangeLoop extends Thread
{
    private MyInteger data;

    public StrangeLoop(MyInteger data)
    {
        this.data = data;
    }

    public void run()
    {
        for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i++)
        {
            int local = data.getValue();
            local++;
            data.setValue(local);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        MyInteger data = new MyInteger();
        StrangeLoop t1 = new StrangeLoop(data);
        StrangeLoop t2 = new StrangeLoop(data);
        t1.start();
        t2.start();
        try
        {
            t1.join();
            t2.join();
        }
        catch (InterruptedException e)
        {
        }
        System.out.println("Final value: " + data.getValue());
    }
}
```

If one thread runs through its loop after the other thread already did that, the output of the program should be `Final value: 20`.

But what could go wrong?
Results like 10,11,...19 are also possible (if the OS switches between the threads).

The values between 10 and 20 are possible? So far, I understand it.

But the correct solution of this exercise is: Any output between 2 and 20 is possible. I don't understand how **2** (for example) should be possible.

Comment: Who says 2 is possible? Your teacher? Your friend? Or is this a well-known exercise?

Comment: @Stefan it is an exercise I have seen previously on SO, I think in the context of an interview question.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You have two threads, T1 and T2. They will each do 10 reads (10R) and 10 writes (10W). Because the reads and writes are synchronized, you can guarantee that they don't happen in parallel; and that the previously-written value is visible in the following read of either thread.

- T1 reads the value 0
- T2 reads and writes the value 9 times (value is now 9)
- T1 writes the value 1

T1 has now done 1R, 1W; T2 has done 9R, 9W.

- T1 reads the value 1
- T2 reads the value 1

(or the other way around: the ordering of these two is unimportant)

T1 has done 2R, 1W; T2 has done 10R, 9W.

- T1 writes 2, then reads and writes 8 times

T1 has done 10R, 10W.

- T2 writes the value 2.

T2 has done 10R, 10W.

The finally-written value is 2, as required.

Comment: but of course. Saw this same question a while back but wasn't able to find it.

Comment: thank you very much. Additionally one could write that 3,4,5,6,7,8 & 9 are of course also possible outputs if even 2 (what you showed) is possible.